# Create regular expression remove word

Tags: regex, grafana

Hello good afternoon!!

I'm new to the world of regular expressions and would like some help creating the following expression!

I have a query that returns the following values:

```
caixa-pod
config-pod
consultas-pod
entregas-pod
monitoramento-pod
vendas-pod
```

I would like the results to be presented as follows:

```
caixa
config
consultas
entregas
monitoramento
vendas
```

In this case, it would exclude the word "-pod" from each value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try `(.*)-pod`. It is not clear, where do you want to use that regexp (so regexp can be different). I guess it is dashboard variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
\b[a-z]*(?=-pod)\b
```

This regex basically tells the regex engine to match

- `\b` a word boundary
- `[a-z]*` any number of lowercase characters in range `a-z` (feel free to extend to whatever is needed e.g. `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches all alphanumeric characters)
- `(?=-pod)` followed by `-pod` but exclude that from the result (positive lookahead)
- `\b` another word boundary

> `\b` matches a word boundary position between a word character and non-word character or position (start / end of string).